# Only first test in class failed when running multiple classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have a really strange problem when running multiple tests in intellij. My first test in class failed because apparently jwt was not valid, but then in the second test in the same class everything is working fine with the same jwt.

If I try to run every class separately everything works fine, also if I run `mvn test` from the terminal, all tests will pass.

[This is my configuration for the test in intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uykgJ.png)

I also tried to set `Fork mode` to `class`, then test passed, but every test run separately, so it takes a while, and also I can't use coverage in `Fork mode`.

edit:
This is my code for init and first test

```
    @BeforeAll
    void init() throws Exception {
        token = login(new LoginRequest("user", "123"));
    }

    private String login(LoginRequest loginRequest) throws Exception {
        ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/auth/login")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(loginRequest)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
        return resultActions.andReturn().getResponse().getHeader(JwtUtilities.HEADER);
    }

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    void findAllTeamsByCreator_ok() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get(PATH)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header(JwtUtilities.HEADER, token))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/hal+json"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.teamDtoList").isNotEmpty());
    }
```

so, I'm not setting any state in my test, and if I create test like this

```
@Test
@Order(1)
void test() {}
```

and then everything else remains the same, my tests will work. It's like something is not loaded in first test.

And it's really strange to me why `mvn test` works fine, but in Intellij I have bug

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something is "state full" in your test cases, so something in the first test is initializing something that is needed in the remaining test cases.

As you are using JUnits, you might make sure all the initialization is done in one of the "Before"-type methods that the framework supports.

It would be helpful to see the code of your first test case to determine what has "state".